# Hide express paid shipping options when stock of the product is 0 or less than 0 (backorder cases) in Wocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I set 2 methods of delivery:

Express shipping 48 hours at a cost which es a % of the total cart $ amount

Normal Free shipping in 29 days

The functionality that I want is the following:
If the stock of the product is = 0 or less than 0 (backorder is allowed), the Express shipping option should be hidden. Just must show the Normal free shipping option.
If the stock of the product is >0, both options should be shown.
If I selected more than one product, and one or more of the products does not have stock, the Express shipping option also should be hidden.

From another answer related to this question, I tried the script showed in the answer.
The problem is the following: in the last part of the script there is a mention to a variable in an external plugin.
How I adapt the code to a more generic woocommerce without that plugin?

Script:

```
/* !Hide Shipping Options Woocommerce */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'hide_shipping_based_on_quantity' ,    10, 1 );

function check_cart_for_oos() {

// load the contents of the cart into an array.
global $woocommerce;
$found = false;
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
    $_product_quantity = $_product->get_stock_quantity();
    $_cart_quantity = $values['quantity'];
    if (($_product_quantity <= 0) || ($_cart_quantity > $_product_quantity)) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
return $found;
}


function hide_shipping_based_on_quantity( $available_methods ) {

// use the function check_cart_for_oos() to check the cart for products with 0 stock.
if ( check_cart_for_oos() ) {

    // remove the rate you want
    unset( $available_methods['table_rate_shipping_next-day'] ); // Replace "table_rate_shipping_next-day" with "table_rate_shipping_your-identifier".
}

// return the available methods without the one you unset.
return $available_methods;
}
```

From: [Remove next day shipping method for out of stock items in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914831/remove-next-day-shipping-method-for-out-of-stock-items-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

In that answer, it's already mentioned to use your own shipping method identifier. So you just need to replace the shipping method identifier with yours.

```
// use the function check_cart_for_oos() to check the cart for products with 0 stock.
if ( check_cart_for_oos() ) {

    // remove the rate you want
    unset( $available_methods['USE_YOUR_OWN_IDENTIFIER_HERE'] ); // Replace "table_rate_shipping_next-day" with "table_rate_shipping_your-identifier".
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I inserted the code that you told me and replaced 'USE_YOUR_OWN_IDENTIFIER_HERE', with 'shipping_method_0_flat_rate1'. But it didn't work (appears a message of fatal error). How can I fix this?

Comment: I assume you might doing a mistake somewhere else too. Can you share your code where you did it also you can do var_dump inside the function to see if you are really getting your available shipping methods inside it?

Comment: I used the code from "Remove next day shipping method for out of stock items in Woocommerce" question and replacing what you told me. Dnd I did it in functions.php file.